# Unable to access other users Office 365 inbox using redemption

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook-redemption

I have a program that uses redemption to access users inbox items.  The program works on in house Exchange server no problem.  However, we are in the process of moving to O365. We are trying to convert the program to connect to Office 365.  It works for the user that is logged into the PC and has Outlook setup.  When I try to access another users mailbox in Exchange online that I have full access permissions to I get an Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore: MAPI_E_LOGON_FAILED".

Has anyone got this to work?  Are there any permission other then full access I need to assign?  Let me know what experience you have had.

Here is the code for the connecting.

```
rdsSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox("user@domain.com", "user@domain.com", "Password")
```

The error occurs on this line when trying to get the inbox.

```
rdfFolder = rdsSession.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
```

If I put my account in there it works. Another users account with full access it doesn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of the thumb is to connect to your (admin) mailbox first using `LogonHostedExchangeMailbox`, and then open the other user's mailbox using `RDOSession.GetSharedMailbox` / `GetSharedDefaultFolder`

Comment: Thank you will try this.

Comment: I am getting this now when using a user@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com domain in the getsharedmailbox( ). 
 {"Could not find the store DN" & vbCrLf & "Could not retrieve autodiscover XML: GetAutodiscoverForEmailAddress: There are no autodiscover servers in the AD for this address" & vbCrLf & "HTTP error 404 from https://uxy.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml" & vbCrLf & "Server response:" & vbCrLf & "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"">"

Comment: I got this working, my issue was with multi-factor authentication on my O365 account. After turning that off and switching to getsharedmailbox and getshareddefaultfolder everything is working.  For both internal and O365 users, since we are still in hybrid mode. Thank you Dmitry.